# JScrollPane for a panel containing a set of labels with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'd like to use a JScrollPane for a panel which has an arbitrary list of labels in it using box layout.   I'm trying to get it so that the scrollbar would appear if there were too many items (labels) to display.

I tried adding a JScrollPane to the panel and then add the labels but then I don't see any scroll bar.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing, you'd normally use a `JList` or `JTable` (if you need custom rendering).

Comment: Yes I could.  I am considering this. In my case this is a game which is keyboard oriented so it's a fair amount more code to implement with a List over a set of labels. But you are right. I could do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you call `validate()` or `revalidate()` on the `JScrollPane` after adding an item, to force the preferred size of the panel to be recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

```
JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
midPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(midPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
midPanel.add(new JLabel("<html><u>Label</u>"));
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
for (Item item : data.getInventory()) {
    inventory.add(box.add(new JLabel(item.getName())));
}

JScrollPane jscrlpBox = new JScrollPane(box);
midPanel.add(jscrlpBox);
add(midPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

From:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JScrollPanetoholdscrollablecomponent.htm

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set the preferred size of the content panel?

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final Box textArea = Box.createVerticalBox();
    final JScrollPane textAreaScroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    textAreaScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,150)); /* essential! */
    JButton addButton = new JButton("ADD");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            textArea.add(new JLabel("abc"));
            textArea.revalidate();
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(textAreaScroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,10)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(addButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

In this example, the scroll bar works correctly, but if you remove the line marked as "essential", it will not work anymore.